# Android Camera Intent Geo-Tagging

Tags: android, geolocation, camera, android-intent

We are utilizing the `Intent.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` for taking a new picture from within our app.

However, we would like to force `geo-tagging` of the pictures.

Is there a way to set the intent to do this or does it rely solely on the default Camera app's setting to "Store Location"?

(Also, it would be nice if this worked for the `ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE` intent as well...)

Comment: I also intrested to know the answer????